# Can you sell on the settlement date?

Tags: stocks, trading

I've understood the concept of freeriding but there is one aspect which my googling hasn't been able to answer.

If I buy on Monday with unsettled cash which is due to be settled on Thursday, I cannot sell *before* Thursday (the settlement day). But am I allowed to sell *on* Thursday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, on the settlement the stock is yours to sell with no risk of freeride or day trading applying.